# Change screen resolution using the terminal (command line) in Wayland - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display, wayland

In X, you could use xrandr, but for Wayland / Ubuntu 18.04, that command doesn't work.  Is there a simple one line command to change the screen display resolution in Wayland / Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: Give this a try (worked for me for Ubuntu 22.04)
https://github.com/douwe-2/SetResolutionForUbuntuWayland/tree/main

Answer (score 4):

(Edit - 2023 : better solution)
I'm using now another tool to deal with the activation/position/primary attributes of my screens : `gnome-monitor-config` from https://github.com/jadahl/gnome-monitor-config/

For me it is more stable than gnome-randr and quite easy to use.
Example to position and activate 3 monitors, from left to right :

- a 3840x2160 primary monitor (on DisplayPort-2)
- a 640x480 monitor (on HDMI-3)
- a 320x240 TV (on VGA-1)

(2640 on the last parameter is 2160+480)

```
$ gnome-monitor-config set -LpM DP-2 -s2 -LM HDMI-3 -y 2160 -LM VGA-1
-y 2640
```

To turn off the non-primary monitors, just omit them :

```
$ gnome-monitor-config set -LpM DP-2 -s2
```

Most applications (including Steam games) start on the primary monitor, so it's also useful to use the -p parameter on another monitor. Example to make "HDMI-3" the primary monitor :

```
$ gnome-monitor-config set -LM DP-2 -s2 -LpM HDMI-3 -y 2160 -LM VGA-1 -y 2640
```

I don't use it (I prefer that my screens use their 'native' resolution fed by EDID), but you can also modify resolution by using `-m` after `set` command. Use `gnome-monitor-config list` to find available modes/resolutions.
Example :

```
$ gnome-monitor-config set -LpM DP-2 -m 1920x1080@60,000
```

`-help` output :

```
 Options:
    Commands:
      list                       List current monitors and current configuration
      set                        Set new configuration
      show                       Show monitor labels
    
    Options for 'set':
     -L, --logical-monitor       Add logical monitor
     -x, --x=X                   Set x position of newly added logical monitor
     -y, --y=Y                   Set y position of newly added logical monitor
     -s, --scale=SCALE           Set scale of newly added logical monitor
     -t, --transform=TRANSFORM   Set transform (normal, left, right, flip)
     -p, --primary               Mark the newly added logical monitor as primary
     -M, --monitor=CONNECTOR     Add a monitor (given its connector) to newly added
                                 logical monitor
```

-- original answer --

I use gnome-randr. Someone created it 1 year ago to "reimplement some of the functionality of 'xrandr' for the gnome desktop using mutter's dbus-api. It currently has not been tested with fractional scaling support."

You can download it here : https://gitlab.com/Oschowa/gnome-randr
Then you :

```
$ chmod +x gnome-randr.py
```

You can also replace the first line by this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and run it

```
$ ./gnome-randr.py
```

It will give you current configuration and names of your monitors, like DP-1 DVI-1 HDMI-1.

Then you can use xrandr syntax :

```
$ ./gnome-randr.py --output DP-1 --rotate normal --mode 1920x1080
```

Help is also available for all possibilities :

```
$ ./gnome-randr.py -h
usage: gnome-randr.py [options]
    where options are:
    --current
    --dry-run
    --persistent
    --global-scale <global-scale>
    --output <output>
        --auto
        --mode <mode>
        --rate <rate>
        --scale <scale>
        --off
        --right-of <output>
        --left-of <output>
        --above <output>
        --below <output>
        --same-as <output>
        --rotate normal,inverted,left,right
        --primary
```