How to create a custom refresh rate for your display? Ubuntu 22.04.4
I would like to change the refresh rate of the laptop display(main monitor) as it has continuous flickering and intermittent white lines and the only options are 60.08Hz or 144.03Hz(like on Windows 11).
By doing some tests on Windows 11 using CRU I managed to significantly reduce these effects by setting the refresh rate to 120Hz.
Searching around I found somewhat dated answers and before doing any damage I preferred to ask you.
Thanks in advance to anyone who will respond.
WAYLAND1 is the laptop display.
This is xrandr output:
Screen 0: minimum 16 x 16, current 2688 x 900, maximum 32767 x 32767
XWAYLAND0 connected 1152x720+0+180 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 410mm x 260mm
1152x720      59.75*+
800x600       59.47
640x480       59.38
320x240       59.52
720x480       59.71
640x400       59.20
320x200       58.96
1024x576      59.58
864x486       59.45
720x400       59.55
640x350       58.91
XWAYLAND1 connected primary 1536x864+1152+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
1536x864     143.88*+
1152x864     143.92
1024x768     143.87
800x600      143.83
640x480      143.85
320x240      142.05
1280x800     143.84
720x480      143.85
640x400      143.37
320x200      141.40
1368x768     143.77
1280x720     143.85
1024x576     143.91
864x486      143.63
720x400      143.88
640x350      143.57

"Searching around I found somewhat dated answers"  show them? Old does not mean invalid... because the way this works has NOT changed over the past years ;)

this for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/1286458/does-wayland-have-an-equivalent-of-xrandr-for-changing-brightness-and-color-temp  or https://askubuntu.com/questions/973499/wayland-how-to-set-a-custom-resolution  or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067018/change-screen-resolution-using-the-terminal-command-line-in-wayland-ubuntu-1   (the 1st one is the youngest ;) )

@Rinzwind thanks so much for replying and for the links.
Next time I will post the links to the answers I found so as to confirm their validity.
Thanks again for your time.
